# Webscraping with python using request issue with geolocation

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, geolocation

I am currently scraping the amazon.com website with request and the use of proxies.

I'm using the request module with python3.

The issue that I am facing is that amazon returns me the results based on the geolocation of the proxy rather than the results for the amazon.com for the US.

How can I make sure that I will get only the results for the amazon.com from the US for the US only?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=a%20circuit'
proxy_dict = # Proxy details in the dictionary form
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_dict, timeout=(3, 3))
htmlText = response.text
# I am than saving the details in a text file.
```

The code works fine, but it does return the results for the location of the proxy.

How can I make sure that the results will be only for the US? 
Shell I perhaps add something on the url  or something on the header?

Comment: Where is your proxy? and what results are you getting?

Comment: Hi @RobertKearns proxies are scattered worldwide (not single proxy or location), and they go at random. In terms of results I am getting all the results required however based on the location of the proxy request.

Comment: were you able to solve this? i am having a similar use case and i am stuck exactly here